# How to insert variable's value to a span tag in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the question is how can I insert the variable index's value to a span tag. I have many submissions and I want show the info of each of them. I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<% @submissions.each do |submission, index| %>
    <tr class="athing">
        <td align="right" valign="top" class="title">
            <span class="rank">index</span>
        </td>      
    <tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to put `index` in a `ruby tag` `<%= %>`

```
<% @submissions.each_with_index do |submission, index| %>
  <tr class="athing">
    <td align="right" valign="top" class="title">
        <span class="rank"><%=index%></span>
    </td>      
  <tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it before but it didn't work. Because I forgot to put _with_index!